# Haskell: converting data from file to Data type

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble converting a list of strings from a text file to a data type I have created called `Film`. I will display the code below:

`Inside the films.txt`

```
"Casino Royale" 
"Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"
2006
"Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"

"Cowboys & Aliens"
"Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"
2011
"Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"

"Catch Me If You Can"
"Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"
2002
"Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"
}
```

My Haskell code:

```
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]

type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)

main ::  IO()
main = do 
      putStr "What is your name?: "
      name <- getLine
      firstdatabase <- readFile "films.txt"
      putStr firstdatabase
      let database = read firstdatabase :: [Film]
      mainLoop database name
```

Any ideas on what I will have to do?

Comment: There are parsing libraries like parsec that can do this sort of thing.  It wouldn't be very difficult to write a parser for a `Film`.  Unfortunately you won't get very far with `read` here, since the `Read` instances for the types you have expect literal haskell values, so you'd need a 4-tuple (with parens) in your database file with a string (with quotes), a list of strings (with brackets), an int, then a list of strings (with brackets), all separated by commas, and then you would need the entire contents of the file to be capable of being interpreted as a literal haskell list, etc etc.

Comment: In short, `read` does not make a good parser.

Comment: @bheklilr: true, though it would also be quite simple to convert that format _to_ Haskell code, and then parse that with `read`. Not really elegant of course, but oh well...

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished pretty easily with parsec:

```
import Text.Parsec
    ( Parsec, ParseError, parse        -- Types and parser
    , between, noneOf, sepBy, many1    -- Combinators
    , char, spaces, digit, newline     -- Simple parsers
    )

-- Parse a string to a string
stringLit :: Parsec String u String
stringLit = between (char '"') (char '"') $ many1 $ noneOf "\"\n"

-- Parse a string to a list of strings
listOfStrings :: Parsec String u [String]
listOfStrings = stringLit `sepBy` (char ',' >> spaces)

-- Parse a string to an int
intLit :: Parsec String u Int
intLit = fmap read $ many1 digit
-- Or `read <$> many1 digit` with Control.Applicative

film :: Parsec String u Film
film = do
    -- alternatively `title <- stringLit <* newline` with Control.Applicative
    title <- stringLit
    newline
    cast <- listOfStrings
    newline
    year <- intLit
    newline
    fans <- listOfStrings
    newline
    return (title, cast, year, fans)
-- Alternatively, you can define it all in one go (with Control.Applicative) as
-- film = (,,,)
--      <$> stringlit     <* newline
--      <*> listOfStrings <* newline
--      <*> intLit        <* newline
--      <*> listOfStrings <* newline
-- Which makes it look very much like your actual file

films :: Parsec String u [Film]
films = film `sepBy` newline
```

Then you can use it as

```
loadDB :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [Film])
loadDB filename = do
    db <- readFile filename
    return $ parse films "films" db

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "What is your name?"
    name <- getLine
    db' <- loadDB "films.txt"
    case db of
        Left err -> do
            putStrLn "Error loading film database:"
            print err
        Right db -> mainLoop db name
```

Comment: I like this answer very much. I think in this case, it would be a little more useful to see all this with a qualified import, even for the data and value constructors. Hard enough to understand this if you're new to Haskell, let alone with needing to constantly jump back and forth from the code to the module source code to see what functions come from where.

Comment: @Mr.F Better?  I believe I got all the Parsec imports included as explicit imports, hopefully I didn't miss one.